# Passing a list or Maybe of a list?

Tags: haskell

When a function accepts a `list` as one of the arguments which can be empty and the function itself deals with its being empty (in other words, it expects it to be empty as well), what's the Haskell way of dealing with that: using a list or Maybe of a list?

Comment: Why do you want to pass a Maybe of a list? I think, it would be better, to implement a second variant of the function, where the list isn't needed as parameter. Then you decide at the call side of the function, if you call it with the list, or if the list isn't needed.

Comment: You may be confused by the fact that some standard functions like `head` require nonempty lists. These functions are now widely considered a misdesign; for the list type is almost always understood that `[]` is a good value. You can use [`NonEmpty`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/NonEmpty-0.1/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html) to express that there will be at least one element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A value of type `[a]` is a list. It's allowed to be empty. A value of type `Maybe [a]` is either `Nothing` or `Just xs`, where `xs` is a possibly empty list. An example: suppose you're writing a function that takes a piece of paper and tells you whether there's a shopping list on it, and, if so, what items are on the shopping list. If I give the function a page of sheet music, it will return `Nothing`. If I give it a page with a heading reading "Shopping list", but nothing else, it will return `Just []`. If I give it a page with a heading reading "Shopping list" and actual items, it will return `Just ["Anchovy milkshake", "Potato juice", "Cow pies", "Chicken milk"]`. This would be represented by type `Maybe [String]`.

Comment: so the answer is both options - list and Maybe list - are accepted?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp, they're both potentially useful, but they mean different things. If you just want a list that may or may not be empty, you don't need to bring `Maybe` into it.

Comment: You're probably most likely to encounter `Maybe [a]` in a slightly more advanced setting (the `Maybe` monad or an `unfold`), but a more realistic simple example is the function `safeTail [] = Nothing; safeTail (_:as) = Just as`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern matching for this:

```
foo [] =
  -- do something if list is empty
  ...

foo (x:xs) =
  -- do something if list is not empty
  ...
```

Comment: you didn't understand the question.